# Remove empty field from selection list

Tags: php, wordpress

Excuse me but I'm quite a novice and I'm trying to remove that empty space from my list.
This is the code I am trying to modify from a wordpress template. 
The categories are loaded in the Wordpress administrator and a parent category can be assigned.

```
<select id="wyz-cat-filter" name="<?php echo $this->name;?>" class="form-control" data-size="5">
    <option value="">
<?php
    echo apply_filters( 'wyz_categories_filter_placeholder', esc_html__( 'Categories...', 'wyzi-business-finder' ) );
?></option>
<?php 
for ( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++ ) {
    echo '<optgroup label="'.$taxonomies[$i]['name'].'">
          <option value="'.$taxonomies[ $i ]['id'].'"></option> 
          </optgroup>';
    if ( isset( $taxonomies[ $i ]['children'] ) && ! empty( $taxonomies[ $i ]['children'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $taxonomies[ $i ]['children'] as $chld ) {
            echo '<option ' . ( $category == $chld['id'] ? 'selected ' : '' ) . 'value="' . $chld['id'] . '">' . $chld['name'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

[See image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSypq.jpg)

[See image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq0wc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing with the following code:

```
<select id="wyz-cat-filter" name="<?php echo $this->name;?>" class="form-control" data-size="5">
<option value=""><?php
echo apply_filters( 'wyz_categories_filter_placeholder', esc_html__( 'Categories...', 'wyzi-business-finder' ) );?></option>
<?php for ( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++ ) {
    echo '<optgroup label="'.$taxonomies[$i]['name'].'"><option value="'.$taxonomies[ $i ]['id'].'"></option></optgroup>';
    if ( isset( $taxonomies[ $i ]['children'] ) && ! empty( $taxonomies[ $i ]['children'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $taxonomies[ $i ]['children'] as $chld ) {
            if ( ! empty( trim( $chld['name'] ) ) ) {
                echo '<option ' . ( $category == $chld['id'] ? 'selected ' : '' ) . 'value="' . $chld['id'] . '">' . $chld['name'] . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
}?>
```

Comment: @pablo79py I updated the code, could you try again?